Broadcasting multiple versions of X_data that pair with the same y_data
My deep learning architecture accepts an input vector with size 512 and an output vector with size 512 too.
The problem is I have X_data version that pairs with the same y_data.
I have these tensors:
(4, 8, 512) -> (batch_size, number of X_data version, input size to model architecture) (list of X_data)

(4, 512) -> (batch_size, output size to model architecture) (y_data)

This means:
X_data[0,0,:] is pairing with y_data[0,:]
X_data[0,1,:] is pairing with y_data[0,:]
...
X_data[0,7,:] is pairing with y_data[0,:]
X_data[1,0,:] is pairing with y_data[1,:]
X_data[1,1,:] is pairing with y_data[1,:]
...
X_data[1,7,:] is pairing with y_data[1,:]
...
X_data[3,7,:] is pairing with y_data[3,:]

What is the final tensor shape of X_data and y_data so that I can train the model?
Could you do that in NumPy?

Use np.repeat or np.tile to transform y into a (4,8,512) array? Then possibly np.reshape both back to (32, 512)?

@Julien but my architecture only accept (batch_size, 512), I guess it can be reshaped into (32, 512)

Well this is crucial information, you should mention that in your post... See edit to comment.

ydata[:, None,:] has a shape of (4,1,512) which in numpy broadcasts with the xdata.  reshape to that shape works as well.

To reshape the arrays into (32, 512) arrays with X_data and y_data matched the way you specify, you could do something like this:
import numpy as np

X_data = np.random.rand(4, 8, 512)
y_data = np.random.rand(4, 512)

X_data, y_data = np.broadcast_arrays(X_data, y_data[:, None, :])
X_data = X_data.reshape(32, 512)
y_data = y_data.reshape(32, 512)
``

